# How to delete duplicated data by column form database

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete, postgresql-9.5

I have a table that has multiple duplicated rows by one column. So I want to clear duplicated datas.

Events Table:

```
event_id,   event_type,     data_id,    data    date
    1       insert              1       x       06.03.2019 13:04
    2       update              1       x1      06.03.2019 13:05
    3       update              1       x11     06.03.2019 13:06
    4       insert              2       y       06.03.2019 13:07
    5       update              1       x111    06.03.2019 13:08
    6       delete              1       x111    06.03.2019 13:09        
    7       update              2       y1      06.03.2019 13:10
    8       update              2       y11     06.03.2019 13:11
    9       update              2       y11     06.03.2019 13:12
```

Each data id has `1` insert, `N` update and `1` delete event rows in table. So I want to delete `N-1` update events but last event will not be deleted.
For example in this table, for `data_id=1` update events are `2,3,5`. I want to delete `2` and `3` but not `5`. Because `5` is last update.

Comment: Last by id or date?

Comment: event_id is incremental and data as well. Does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With EXISTS:

```
delete from tablename t
where
  event_type = 'update'
  and exists (
    select 1 from tablename 
    where 
      data_id = t.data_id 
      and
      event_type = 'update'
      and 
      event_id > t.event_id
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as an exists:

```
DELETE
FROM your_table t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM your_table t2
              WHERE t1.data_id = t2.data_id AND
                    t2.event_id < t1.event_id AND
                    t2.event_type = 'update') AND
      t1.event_type = 'update';
```